How can I program two ev3 bricks at the same time with one program?
I want to be a program two EV3 bricks in Lego Mindstorms Education Ev3 software

Can you answer? I want to run 8 motors at the same time.

How can I contact you?

Please check the linked question. If what is written there doesn't work for you, edit your post with the details: what have you tried and how did it not work. Then people here will be able to post answers. You contact the community by writing and editing your question and by adding comments to questions and answers. See more in the [tour] and [help] pages.
